# DropDownListFor() and 500 Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting a 500 error when I post my AJAX form via clicking the submit button. The controller that handles the AJAX post is getting the data fine but when I return the Partial View, via this line, I am getting the 500:

```
return PartialView("_SiteSurveyNewClubTeam", model);
```

The reason I am returning the partial back instead of a HTTP status code is because if I don't, one of my dynamic dropdowns comes back unpopulated. Maybe I am pinting myself into a corner, here.

The data types supplied in the offending DropDownListFor() I believe are correct and in the right order: `(string, IList<SelectListItem>)`

**Error**

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'DistrictSelected' is of type 'System.String' 
but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.
```

**View Model Declarations**

```
public IList<SelectListItem> DistrictSelect { get; set; }
public string DistrictSelected { get; set; }
```

**Source of the Error is this line in my View**

```
<span class="formColumn2">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DistrictSelected, Model.DistrictSelect)</span>
```

Not sure why I am getting this. Any ideas?

Thanks

**Here is the code that processes the AJAX form post**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessFormANewClubTeam(FormANewClubTeamViewModel model)
{
    var httpStatus = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    var cosponsors = new List<NewClubSponsor>();
    var errorMessages = new StringBuilder();
    var tasks = new NewClubBuilderTasks();
    var clubKeyNumber = tasks.GetClubKeyNumber();
    var masterCustomerId = tasks.GetMasterCustomerId();
    bool exceptionRaised = false;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {


        if (model.NewClub_Id > 0)
        {
                //Load the entity to be partially-updated
                NewClub newClub = db.NewClubs.Single(nc => nc.Id == model.NewClub_Id);

                //Set the values for the fields to be updated
                newClub.District = model.DistrictSelected;
                newClub.Division = model.DivisionSelected;
                newClub.Region = Utility.Personify.GetRegionFromDistrict(newClub.District);
                newClub.ClubCounselorMasterCustomerId = model.ClubCounselorMasterCustomerId;
                newClub.ClubCounselorContact = model.ClubCounselorContact;
                newClub.ClubCounselorEmail = model.ClubCounselorEmail;
                newClub.ClubCounselorPhone = model.ClubCounselorPhone;
                newClub.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;

                try
                {
                    //Execute the UPDATE
                    var dbResult = db.SaveChanges() > 0;
                    httpStatus = HttpStatusCode.OK;

                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    //Catch exceptions here
                }

           // return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int) httpStatus);
           return PartialView("_SiteSurveyNewClubTeam", model);

    } else {

            var errors = ModelState
            .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
            .Select(x => new {x.Key, x.Value.Errors})
            .ToArray();

            return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int) httpStatus);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the ajax?

Comment: Yes, the AJAX form does post fine

Comment: Sorry, I mean paste the ajax code here...

Comment: Can you show how is your DirectSelect collection is generated?

Comment: in your partial are you returning an IList<> or a string ?

Comment: also would be helpful to see the whole post action that returns your parital.

Comment: I added the method that processes the ajax form and returns the partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to repopulate your select list items in your DistrictSelect list in the post action. Your viewmodel that was posted has DistrictSelect  as null, this is why you are getting that exception when you render your partial.

Comment: Wow, thanks for catching that. I was looking in every other place